# which code editor is free and can upload by ftp by a keystroke, and have a side panel for folder browsing?

Tags: text, editor, notepad++, textmate

I like PhpEd because with CTRL-SHIFT-S, it will upload to the test server, so no need to switch to the FTP client, locate the file, and upload it.

I also like TextMate because the display is nice (Monaco font is less cramped than Lucida Console and easy to look at than Courier)... and also with a left panel for folder and file listing.

So on the PC / Mac / Linux, is there such an editor that can do

1) Easy FTP
2) side panel file/folder listing
3) good look font
4) auto indent
5) auto re-indent
6) show matching { and }, and matching <div> and </div>

I tried a few... like Notepad++, jEdit, or Programmer's Editor and don't seem to find these features yet.  Do you know an editor that comes close?

Comment: If it has a lot of cup holders, that'd be awesome, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use PSPad - if you open a file from FTP, every time you save it is uploaded to the FTP server.

It also supports writing scripted macros.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs can do *anything* any other editor can do, you just have to learn Scheme/Lisp to write the macros :-).

I don't doubt that Vim could also do this (I'm a Vim man myself and I've written macros but I've never felt the need to do specifically what you ask for).

It's a bit of a contrived question; you may as well ask which editor can:

- capitalize COBOL code.
- add sequence numbers.
- upload it to the mainframe.
- send an SMS message to the operator to start a compiler run.

*Most* editors are incredibly configurable nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer a solution outside the box, and rather than inventing an IDE that can do a specific thing, I use tools that bring the FTP and SFTP to me.

In particular, [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows/) (formerly, sftpdrive) will mount remote machines over sftp as local drives. That way, any local app will treat the mounted drive as if it were local and you wouldn't have to jump through hoops to save data remotely.

Similarly, for FTP, there are methods such as the one described [here](http://cybernetnews.com/2007/09/27/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/).

If you have access to samba on the remote machine, then use that. It's the fastest and best implemented approach IO-wise and you can mount samba mounts directly as drives in Windows. This is my preferred method of development using a shared dev box in the office.

Hope this helps.

P.S. My favorite editor is EditPadPro because it integrates with RegexBuddy and provides true full Perl-style regex support, along with all the standard stuff like code highlight, plugins (like XML/HTML formatter), etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer of your questions is Panic Coda. just setup a site with a local folder and associate remote folder. now every change you made on that local folder it will automatically mirror to the remote folder. not only when you edit a file but also when you create sub-folders or create new files or put some image there.

Answer (score 0):

[Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) has FTP/SFTP editing.

Answer (score 0):

I've used lots of different editors, but HTMLEdit has served me well. It has the ftp part and extensions, but maybe not all your required bells and whistles. It's for Windows